# Where are network stream stored

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm new in programing and especialy in the network world
Till now i have learned some things about tcp, sync and async programing and understand more or less how things go ( i even wrote a simple client-server program)
 But there are still a few issues i couldn't find answer for them.
1. If i (client) write into a network stream (to server) but the server doesn't read the stream untill i run some command. What happens to those bits? Are they being stored somewhere on the server side until they will be read?
2. When i read the "stream" with stream.read command (c#) Where do i actually read from?

It would be nice to be directed to arelevant reading material
I thinkvit will also help me understand more async programing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some documentation related to the NetworkStream class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.7.2

Also, TCP provides tracking of sent packets, with validation whether the sent packets have been received. As opposed to UDP, where there is no validation whether sent packets have been received. 
https://www.howtogeek.com/190014/htg-explains-what-is-the-difference-between-tcp-and-udp/

So it depends on whether it's TCP or UDP in this case.

Also, the difference between for example a FileStream and a NetworkStream in your case, is that a FileStream uses a file as a way to store information (on a hard drive, typically), where another application can read it any time, while a NetworkStream requires both applications having a connection to be active at the same time, because information is being sent/received via a cable typically. It doesn't have any persistent form of storage by default.

EDIT: Stream.Read is probably a blocking function that listens on a port until it decides to stop listening. A server needs to be listening (with Stream.Read) before it can receive information. 
In the case of TCP, a server and client first need to complete a 3-way handshake before they can exchange information. https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If i (client) write into a network stream (to server) but the server doesn't read the stream untill i run some command. What happens to those bits?

The data you write into stream will be passed to your OS kernel where it will be scheduled and eventually send over the network. The output queue may be filled, in this case sending function may whether wait, or refuse to send, or wait asynchronously - it depends.

After the data is sent from the client and received on the server, it is collected, assembled and checked in the kernel of the server OS. If everything's fine, the data will wait in input queue until you read it.

> Are they being stored somewhere on the server side until they will be read?

So yes, your understanding is correct.

> 2. When i read the "stream" with stream.read command (c#) Where do i actually read from?

I don't know C# specifics, but let me pose it this way - on this level of abstraction, data is always read from kernel; from a piece of memory of the receiving computer. The function can wait for data to appear (optionally allowing other tasks to run in the meantime). I wouldn't expect anything low-level here. I also won't be surprised if your stream reader can buffer data or give it our in batches (e. g. readline method), but again - I don't know C# specifics.